# How do I make a thread sleep for the UI to give it some task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to launch a thread when an application starts and wait for UI to give it some work without using BackgroundWorker. This thread sleeps when no work is given, and wakes up when the ui asks it do something.

More details:

Simple WPF App: I have a StorageClass to copy files to long term storage. This class is part of the WPF application. When a user clicks a button to store the file to long term storage(Low speed array), I want a thread to copy this file from a highspeed storage array to long term storage. These are large files and I dont want the UI to be blocked. I would like to use one thread that waits for instruction to transfer. Hope this gives more clarity on what I am trying to do.

Comment: Too vague...  Define "give it some work"...  Though I strongly suspect what you're looking for (provided you are in .NET 4 or above) is a `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Comment: Have not done anything yet. Just trying. But will look at your comment James. I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: Cool, i just added some code blocks...

Comment: Starting a new thread won't block the UI thread.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `BackgroundWorker`?  It is designed to do exactly this.

Comment: Because it is too easy. Being serious. what happens, if we have multiple instructions to the background worker thread to transfer before it finished the first? Wont it spawn multiple threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0 or above, I'd recommend the TPL over threading directly, and I'd recommend using a `BlockingCollection<T>` as a way that the UI can "give some work" via the collection for the consumer to do.

The consumer can then be a long-running `Task` (again, from the TPL) that consumes from the `BlockingCollection<T>`, in this way, you don't need any sleep or manual artifacts like that, the `BlockingCollection<T>` lets you block on a wait for a given period of time, then resume once an item is ready to consume.

So you could define a cancellation token source, blocking collection, and task as:

```
    private BlockingCollection<Transaction> _bin = new BlockingCollection<Transaction>();
    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Task _consumer;
```

And your consumer method could be defined as:

```
    private void ConsumeTransactions()
    {
        // loop until consumer marked completed, or cancellation token set
        while (!_bin.IsCompleted && !_tokenSource.Token.IsCancelRequested)
        {
            Transaction item;

            // try to take item for 100 ms, or until cancelled 
            if (_bin.TryTake(out item, 100, _tokenSource.Token)
            {
                // consume the item
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you'd fire off the task when your form loads by doing:

```
// when you have a task running for life of your program, make sure you
// use TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning.  This typically sets up its own
// dedicated thread (not pooled) without having to deal with threads directly
_consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(ConsumeTransactions, _tokenSource.Token, 
                                  TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

And then add items by doing:

```
        _bin.TryAdd(someTransaction);
```

Where `Transaction` is just whatever you define your unit of work to perform...

Then, finally, when your application wants to shut down, it can do:

```
_bin.CompleteAdding();
```

Which tells the consumer that no more items will ever be added to the queue, this will make the `TryTake()` return `false`, and exit the loop since `_bin.IsCompleted` will then be `true`.

Your long running task can then loop on the blocking get until the cancellation token (also TPL) is set to tell it to shut down...

Comment: Excited I am working on based on your jumpt start.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that using a `BackgroundWorker` instead of `Tasks` would result in almost identical code.  You would simply be adding the `ConsumeTransactions` method as an event handler to `DoWork` instead of using `Task.StartNew` to begin running it in the background.

Comment: @Servy: True, just mentioned the `Task`s because I'm more a server guy.  The main point being that he can use the `BlockingCollection<T>` so that he doesn't have to "spin" or "sleep" his thread/task, he can just attempt to take and it does the rest.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare My point is simply that this is a good approach, and it will work regardless of the mechanism that you use to run some code in a non-UI thread.  You can explicitly new up a thread and start that and it's practically the same.  The answer is more universal than just a `Task` based approach.  (That's not a bad thing, it's a good thing.)

Comment: James and all if I used backgroundworker thread: what happens, if we have multiple instructions to the background worker thread to transfer before it finished the first instruction? Wont it spawn multiple threads? The idea is I want this to be queued for a single thread to address it. With that said is Backgroundworker thread a good choice? I am diving deep into James' solution because of my concern with multiple request coming before the first request is complete

Comment: @user1549435 you could have the BackgrounWorker consume from the BlockingCollection<T>.  If you are thinking the GUI will be queueing up several work items before the previous ones finish, then I'd definitely go with the BlockingCollection<T> either being consumed by a Task, or BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @user1549435 - Really the best part of BGW is the notification interface, which is easy to create in other ways.  TPL is nice because it gives you a lot of control to chain and nest tasks.  Personally, I prefer the TPL, myself, but then again I'm more of a server programmer than a client programmer.

Comment: James: I went with TPL. There is no need to notify users in the scenario. One thing I am wondering if the long running task be running at low priority or high priority by default. I want this to be lowest priority.

Comment: James: One more clarification. Can I suspend the task on network issue and continue upon network available? I used the .NET network class to determine connectivity.

Comment: @user1549435: That logic would be largely your own.  You can have the process periodically check for network connectivity and then just skip work for a period.